# IE and Chrome, does not print Google map base layer. FireFox does

Tags: google-maps, openlayers

I am using GeoServer for extracting polygons from shapefile then I use them with OpenLayers JS API and project them on Google maps base layer. All set, everything works fine.

I display 2 WMS layers over Google maps base layer, they looks fine in print preview in all browsers but when I print them

FireFox: Got correct print, all the layers printed correctly.
IE/Chrome: only last layer added to map is printed if its not gmap layer.

`map.addLayers([gmap, wms1, wms2, vectors]);`

here the polygon from `wms2` is printed, if I switch them then wms1 is printed and google layer is never printed (even if I put that in last).

Please suggest if you know any workaround or any problem in the way I am doing it. I have already checked advanced option in IE to print image and background but no effect.

Thank you.

Anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The problem was with 'opacity': 0.80 parameter while getting polygon from both WMS layers.Although I don't know it for sure but it's the problem with printing Opaque images in IE/Chrome.

In case anybody face the same problem, don't use opacity.